# How to populate an activity from ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I am developing an application the returns data from a MYSQL database and displays the results in a listview. This consists of a Name, Address and a Number. When an item in the listview is selected i want it to open another page that displays the details of the item list you clicked on. How would I go about this?I know I will have to use the onListItemClick method but how can I create a page template that will be loaded with the information from whatever item in the list you clicked on? Thanks

Here is the code I use to connect to the database and query it and then display the results in a listview:

```
public class HttpExample extends ListActivity {

TextView httpStuff;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // setContentView(R.layout.httpex);
    setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
    httpStuff = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHttp);

    GetMethodEx test = new GetMethodEx();
    String returned;
    try {
        returned = test.getInternetData();
        httpStuff.setText(returned);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.main,
            new String[] { "name", "address", "number" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle, R.id.item_number });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}

public class GetMethodEx {

    public String getInternetData() throws Exception {

        BufferedReader in = null;
        String data = "";
        String returnString = "";

        // httpGet

        try {

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI website = new URI("http://192.168.0.10/connect.php");
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(website);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response
                    .getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String l = "";
            String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");

            while ((l = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(l + nl);
            }
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            // return data;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // parse json data
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id", String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("name",
                        "ShopName:" + json_data.getString("shopname"));
                map.put("address",
                        "Address: " + json_data.getString("address"));
                map.put("number", "Number: " + json_data.getInt("number"));
                mylist.add(map);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return returnString;

    }

}

}
```

Comment: add your code details and explain pls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is pass data via Intents.

From the onListItemClick method, have the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("NAME", name);
intent.putExtra("ADDRESS", address);
// etc

startActivity(intent)
```

Then, in the new Activity's onCreate() method, do the following:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String name = intent.getStringExtra("NAME");
// ...etc
```

For further info, there's a lesson on this in the Android Training site, called [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have some options.
You can pass the relevant data you need to pass in pieces via [intent extras](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

A common pattern for activities to receive intent extras is to create a static method to have that activity create the extras bundle. something like this:

```
public static Intent createIntent(Activty activity, String myExtra)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MyActivity.class);
        if(myExtra != null) intent.putExtra(MY_EXTRA, myExtra);
        return intent;
    }
```

You can pass more complex objects as extras by [serializing](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) them or [parceling](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) them.
Good luck!